# MSSQL question marks in php on windows with apache

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

And php 5.6 on Apache.

In SQL Server I have DB with COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI.

In SQL Server Management Studio I can see everything without any problems.

BUT

Then I do this:

```
<?php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql = "SELECT NAME FROM NAMES";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['NAME'];
}
```

I get ??????????????? question marks instead words.

Important condition: I can use only `sqlsrv_connect()`.

Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: you didn't tell your output environment that you're spitting out cyrillic text, so it'll render your text in whatever charset that environment is using, e.g. iso8859.

Comment: What you mean output environment? Where from iso8859 goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.

If Microsoft (burn in hell) do not have language pack for language you use in your SQL server, then you will see question marks.

To solve it - instal language pack to your server copy.

Thank you, microsoft again, for you stupidity and your utf-8 dislike.

Answer (score 1):

Set the correct charset in your browser:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

or via PHP with:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Comment: It's not a browser problem. sqlsrv_fetch_array get question marks.

Comment: @AlexanderMatrosov Doubtful. Whatever you're using to view the output likely doesn't know how to visually represent the data. If you're not seeing this in a browser then you need to fix the encoding issue in whatever it is you're viewing it with.

Comment: Anyway, this method didn't work. In Chrome with ANY enoding I see questions